# Merge levels for categorical levels in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge, levels

I am wondering, how to merge levels of a categorical variable in Python ?

I have the following dataset:

```
dataset['Reason'].value_counts().head(5).
Reason  Count
0       339
7       125
11      124
3        82
0        65
```

Now, I want to merge the first and last occurrence of, so that the output looks like:

```
dataset['Reason'].value_counts().head(5)
Reason  Count
0       404
7       125
11      124
3        82
2        52
```

In order to get to the reason, I have had to split a string, which might have led to the various levels in the `reason` column.

I have tried to use the `loc` function, but I am wondering, whether there is smarter way to do it:

```
dataset.loc[dataset['Reason'] == '0' , ['Reason']] = 'On request'
dataset.loc[dataset['Reason'] == '0 ' , ['Reason']] = 'On request'
```

Thanks, Michael.

Comment: if the dtype is a string you can use `series.str.strip()` before doing value_counts

Comment: Hi Anky, thank you for that hint ! I was not aware of this and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @anky_91 mentioned use [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) if all values are strings:

```
dataset['Reason'].str.strip().value_counts().head(5)
```

If some values are numeric first cast to `string`s by [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
dataset['Reason'].astype(str).str.strip().value_counts().head(5)
```